# How to use hosted application pool identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, authentication, impersonation

I have a WCF RESTful service, it is hosted on IIS 7. I am using webHttpBinding binding with the WCF service.

This service is having a application pool for which I specified a custom account identity(I specified user name & password)

Anonymous access is enabled for the WCF service.

From inside the WCF service code I want to make a HttpWebRequest to another server. But I want to use the same context (identity) under which my application pool is running.

How can I achieve it, do I need to use impersonation for this? or is there any better way for it.

Annu

Comment: Is the 'other server' application using windows authentication?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the [`UseDefaultCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.usedefaultcredentials) property of the `HttpWebRequest` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on if the other service supports Windows Authentication. If it does then you can either

```
 request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

or

```
 request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```